# TCPDF - How to save PDF to server including form values?

Tags: php, tcpdf

So I'm using TCPDF to generate a PDF with multiple Text Areas in a form. On Submit I want to save this PDF including the newly added Text on my Server but I can't find a way to do it.

I'm using a form like this:
https://tcpdf.org/examples/example_054/

If I change the Output to F I just save the blank PDF to my server.

Any hint what I miss? Have the feeling it's just a simple setting thing.